# dynamic xml with php

Tags: php, xml, directorysearcher

Trying to write a XML file populated with information fetched from a directory listing but I can't figure out how to get the createElement menthods to play nice with dynamic content.

I'm tempted to just hard code in the tags like a dynamic table and then just take the entire output and post it to the xml file but i'm not sure how to drop in preformated tags into the xml either.

my XML needs to be formated as thus

```
<CONTENT>
    <GALLERY name="**HARDCODED DATA**">
        <CATEGORY name="**HARDCODED DATA BASED FROM DIRECTORY SEARCH 1**" desc="**HARDCODED DATA BASED FROM DIRECTORY SEARCH 1**" thumb="**HARDCODED DATA BASED FROM DIRECTORY SEARCH 1**">
            <ITEM>
                <file_path>**dynamic content from directory search**</file_path>
                <file_width>**HARDCODED**</file_width>
                <file_height>**HARDCODED**</file_height>
                <file_title>**dynamic content from directory search**</file_title>
                <file_desc>**Loaded from a seperate txt file, index to match with the index of the dir file**</file_desc>
                <file_image>**Loaded from a seperate txt file, index to match with the index of the dir file**</file_image>
                <featured_image>**Loaded from a seperate txt file, index to match with the index of the dir file**</featured_image>
                <featured_or_not>**Loaded from a seperate txt file, index to match with the index of the dir file**</featured_or_not>
            </ITEM>
****loop through for next ITEM****
        </CATEGORY>
****start next category from secody directory search content****
    </GALLERY>
****start gallery 2 and 3 here, same format at gallery 1****
</CONTENT>
```

Comment: Please, add you PHP code if you want more help.

Comment: there are links further down comment with the full source, here it is again http://maskedriders.info/Sources/Power%20Rangers/webplayer.phps

Answer (score 1):

you can use urlencode() function to not break up XML

```
echo urlencode("<table><tr><td>Encoded data</td></tr></table>");
```

you would get

```
%3Ctable%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3EEncoded+data%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%3C%2Ftable%3E
```

try to decode that with urldecode() you would get

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Encoded data</td>
  </tr> 
 </tbody>
</table>
```

*Edited*i think i found your problem , is at "Generate list" the tags
table
tr
td
ar considered HTML markup tags while from line 191 until line 200
item
file_path
file_width
file_height
file_title
file_desc
file_image
featured_image
featured_or_not
are considered XML tags and should be parsed instead of dumping the XML in HTML body.
what you should if you want the visitor of your website to have access to the XML and parse as he/she wishes the XML is just dump XML markup into file, but without the HTML tags instead use custom tags such as  and  and user should parse XML IF he wants to produce an HTML table out of it OR include the encoded  output of "GenerateList" and print BUT this way the XML tags that i mention above WONT BE give you the expecting result of a HTML table intead replace them with TD to represent a cell in the HTML table.
hope it helped

Comment: would that work with custome tags like <category></catagory> and while logically i can write all this to a single pgp variable how do i then pass this variable to the xml parser would createElement() work with a huge feed of code, instead of a single tag?

Comment: it will work in XML markup as long as tag names are valid ( possible typo at <category></cat>a<gory> ), you can pass the encoded value as a parameter to 
createElement("tag",urlecode($HTML_MARKUP));
to parse that simply..parse the xml and at the tags/attributes that you expect to be "hardcoded" just use urldecode() to retrieve HTML markup from encoded value.

Comment: so the end result would look somthing like <tag>$htmlvalue</tag> right?

Comment: well it seems to be creating the right formated XML http://maskedriders.info/Sources/Power%20Rangers/playlist.xml
however it is also outputting it to the browser http://maskedriders.info/Sources/Power%20Rangers/webplayer.php
and the web player cant seem to read it right

Comment: in you xml i don't see HTML markup instead i see more xml markup that you could parse with simpleXML, i suggested the urlencode function for encoding html markup into an xml file by parsing with simplexml and simply decode/print values you produce html markup.
this is way i have you many times that i store some html in xml files without breaking up the xml markup!

Comment: i did use URencode first i generate the tags and throw them into a variable in normal form then i take the entire variable, encode that, then use urldecode when i pass it to the xml parser

     here is a link to a phps source version of the web player http://maskedriders.info/Sources/Power%20Rangers/webplayer.phps

Comment: The user should never actually see the XML, the idea is i have a series of directories i'm uploading files to, i want php to read the directory and feed the results into custom XML code that is then read by the flash player on the back end to pupulate the player, the user never interer acts wit hthe XML content the table content is there to show them the file list but the XML should all be invisible and on the back end for the flash player

Comment: then you should have no need to urlencode things, if that is the way the XML is manipulated, its ok! now if you want the markup to AUTO-generate on changes make a cron job to autorun every X minutes and recheck and generate new XML with changes applied, other than that you can't embed any code from xml markup (not sure) unless is some javascript which will not give you the functionality you need! on the other hand you can make a PHP script that will check all your directories, with header for XML file, this i believe is the best way to solve your problem.

Comment: the way i have it set up is when you load the php page it searches the directory and build the xml, might be a bit inefficient but for this stage of development rebuilding on load works fine, i removed the url encodes from the code but it's still printing out the xml and i;m not sure why, and the flash player still isn't working even through when i had coded the xml it works just fine
http://maskedriders.info/Sources/Power%20Rangers/webplayer.php
as a point of reference if i load this hand coded xml it works fine, http://maskedriders.info/Sources/Power%20Rangers/playlist_ORIG.xml

Comment: Ok think i fixed the problem withthe xml being output and not saving right (had to manually convert any & to and) the XML file loads the entire content but still wont load, any ideas?
http://maskedriders.info/Sources/Power%20Rangers/playlist.xml

Comment: found the problem needed to use loadXML instead od apendchild

Answer (score 0):

found the problem needed to use loadXML instead od apendchild